# Different response of the axios get depending on the token

Tags: vue.js, axios, get, response

I'm currently implementing the liked function.

so, When entering the component, an Axios `get` request is made with async created().

In postman, axios get requests from members and axios get requests from non-members depend on the presence or absence of tokens.

if I put the token in the header and make an axios get request, I make an axios get request when I'm a member, and if I make an axios get request without putting the token in the header, I make an axios get request when I'm a non-member.

As above, In postman, the response of the axios get is different depending on whether you put the token in the header or not. But, In my code, Even if I put a token in the header and make an axios get request, the backend log outputs that I have made an axios get request as a non-member.

How can I get the response differently when I make an axios get request depending on the non-member and the member?

```
getHeart(state, payload) {
  const {id} = payload
  axios.get(`http://??.???.???.???:????/api/books/${id}/heart`, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer` + localStorage.getItem('user-token')
    }
  })
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res)
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
  })
}
```

My axios get code is like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you don't have a space between 'Bearer' and token, try:

```
Authorization: `Bearer ` + localStorage.getItem('user-token')
```

or even:

```
Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('user-token')}`
```